# Combining symbols in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

I have two arrays, one with symbols and another with strings.

```
a = [:man, :woman]
b = ["one", "two"]
```

I'm trying to combine every symbol with each string in the array so that the output would be:

```
[:man_one, :man_two, :woman_one, :woman_two]
```

I've tried

```
b = b.to_s
q = []
a.each do |n|
  q.push (n.to_s + b.each {|w| "_" + w}).to_sym
end
p q
```

But this gives me an error. How can I create the new symbols?

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward way is this:

```
a.product(b).map{|arr| arr.join("_").to_sym}
#=> [:man_one, :man_two, :woman_one, :woman_two]
```

Comment: Alternatively `a.product(b).map { |g, n| :"#{g}_#{n}" }` – rarely seen, but interpolation also works with [symbol literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols).

Comment: @Stefan Opps. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems while trying to achieve your expected output:

Converting b to String gives you nothing else than `"[\"one\", \"two\"]"`, which isn't iterable, so I guess that mess everything.

In the other hand it seems you're trying to iterate on a, to iterate on b then, but pushing to q right the value of the elements of a to String plus a call on each to b, seems to give you nothing.

With a slight tweak you can make that work:

```
a = [:man, :woman]
b = ["one", "two"]
q = []

a.each do |n|
    b.each do |w|
        q << ("#{n}_#{w}").to_sym
    end
end

p q
# [:man_one, :man_two, :woman_one, :woman_two]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product)

```
a = [:man, :woman]
b = ["one", "two"]
a.product(b).map { |arr| arr.join('_') }.map(&:to_sym)
```

Your error is because you're trying to call `each` on a `String` (b), because you converted it with `to_s` a few lines up.

If you want to do this with the temporary variable, q, you can write it like this:

```
a=[:man, :woman ]
b=["one", "two"]
q=[]

a.each do |tmp_a|
  b.each do |tmp_b|
    q.push((tmp_a.to_s + '_' + tmp_b).to_sym)
  end
end

puts q
```

Comment: What are you trying to show using `permutation`? It raises an error.

Comment: I mean to write "product", but I was looking at the permutation documentation when i wrote this and didn't go back and test it. The link went to the right documentation, but nothing else was right :) Good catch, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yet another riff on the nested loop without mutating an external variable within the loops

```
a = [:man, :woman]
b = ["one", "two"]

q = a.flat_map do |n|
  b.map do |w|
    "#{n}_#{w}".to_sym
  end
end

p q
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another example of https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-product, passing a block:

```
res = []
a.product(b){ |e| res << e.join('_').to_sym }
res #=> [:man_one, :man_two, :woman_one, :woman_two]
```